# CoreGraphics: Use coordinates from 0 to 1?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to use a normalized coordinate system (from 0.0 to 1.0) instead of using pixel coordinates when drawing stuff with CoreGraphics? It would certainly make a lot of things easier...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a CGAffineTransform. I do this in an app. keep all coordinates normalized to -1.0 to 1.0, create a transform based on the size of the view I am drawing into.

Example:

```
CGAffineTransform translateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(offset.x, offset.y);
```

One can transform each point or create a path and transform the entire path:

```
CGMutablePathRef transformedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddPath(transformedPath, &transform, path);
```

As @yurish points out one can also use `CGContextScaleCTM`, `CGContextTranslateCTM`, etc. instead of scaling the points/path if that works better for you.

Comment: How can we normalize all coordinates to -1.0 to 1.0? Can you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: In one case I have coordinates in a plist file that I created normalized. In another case I track the users location, get the offset from the center of the view and then divide by 1/2 of the view size. In my case I save this to a file and later I will read the file and draw the points into a path, create a `CGAffineTransform` based on the view size, transform the path and draw it in `DrawRect`.

Comment: Apologies if I am asking too much, but could you please provide a little hands-on example (i.e. code or a portion of the plist you have) in your answer so that others and I could grasp this idea better? Thanks.

Comment: My plist is specific to my app but here is an example of an entry in an array for a stock form: `<dict> <key>x</key><real>-0.287</real> <key>y</key><real>-0.500</real> </dict>` My dynamically generated paths are an `NSKeyedArchive` of a data model.

Answer (score 0):

Core graphics does not use pixel coordinates. It uses abstract points that are converted to pixels using current transformation matrix (CTM). You can use the normalized coordinate system if you adjust CTM appropriately (`CGContextScaleCTM` etc) .

Comment: Well, I meant that the default certainly seems to correspond to pixels (the coordinate system on the iPad is 1024 x 768...)... OK, I would have done what you've suggested (just scaling the viewport down by its width and height), but it seemed too simple, so I asked...

Comment: The default differs for retina and non retina displays. On devices with retina display the default is 1 point = 2 pixels.